# Run many commands in Linux Mint quickly

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, automation, linux-mint

I'm very much learning my way around the command line. I have several commands I want to occasionally run, mostly on a restart, but at other misc times as well. Can I have some kind of file which can contain these commands and execute the file from the command line so that they are all ran at once? Would this be the general correct approach? And if so, how would I actually achieve this? Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an "init script".

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html

Answer (score 0):

This enables you to define the behaviour of several services, and then determine in what run level you want them to start / stop at (EG: run level 6 for restart).

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You might also benefit from some "alias"'es in your shell (assuming you are using BASH).

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html